# TypeError(Expected sequence or array-like) when assessing Decision Tree model in Python

Tags: python, classification, typeerror, decision-tree

I am working with Kaggle's Churn Modeling Dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/shrutimechlearn/churn-modelling), trying to predict customers who are going to leave the service.

The initial dataset looks like this:

```
RowNumber  CustomerId   Surname  CreditScore Geography Gender  Age  
 0          1    15634602  Hargrave          619    France  Female   42
```

After wrangling the data, the dataset looks like this:

```
CreditScore Age Tenure  Balance NumOfProducts   HasCrCard   IsActiveMember  EstimatedSalary Germany Spain   Male
       0    619 42  2   0.00    1                  1        1               101348.88       0           0     0
```

I then split the data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 0)
```

... fit and predict the model:

```
from sklearn import tree
dectree_model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dectree_fit = dectree_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
dectree_prediction = dectree_fit.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I then try to validate the model:

```
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, dectree_prediction))
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, dectree_prediction))
```

but then I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-c8b0efbc711d> in <module>
      1 # Decision tree
----> 2 print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, 
    dectree_prediction))
      3 print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, 
   dectree_prediction))
   ...
   TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeClassifier'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling, [sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), expects you to feed y_true and y_pred - the ground truth and the estimated targets.

The dectree_prediction variable you provide for y_pred, however, is not the prediction of the estimator, but the estimator itself (that's what the [fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) function returns).

Seems like the actual predictions can be obtained with the dedicated predict function (as shown in [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-tree-regression-py)).